# How to install ecpg (postgres embedded compiler) on centos8?

Tags: centos, postgresql

I'm trying to get [pgsanity](https://github.com/markdrago/pgsanity) to work on CentOS8.

I used to use

`sudo yum install postgresql-devel`

but it seems that does not provide the `ecpg` package anymore.

What would the correct way be to get `ecpg` available?

Answer (score 1):

I sucessfully install pg12 ecpg tools by installing from the pgdg stuff 
( see at https://yum.postgresql.org/repopackages.php ) :

```
rpm -ivh pgdg-redhat-repo-latest.noarch.rpm

#choose version to disable repo (keep pg12 in my case)
yum-config-manager --disable pgdg94
yum-config-manager --disable pgdg95
yum-config-manager --disable pgdg96
yum-config-manager --disable pgdg10
yum-config-manager --disable pgdg11

dnf -qy module disable postgresql

dnf -y install postgresql12-devel
```

I was surprised about location once it was installed:

```
/usr/pgsql-12/
```

PGDG rpm is here : https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/reporpms/EL-8-x86_64/